# how to add expandablelistview to a list view

Tags: android

Is there a way to add expandablelistview to a listview as making nested expandablelistview is becoming very difficult and since no satisfactory solution are available online. Also is there any other alternative way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See the API Demos application in the Android SDK.

You will access it from the menu : Views > Expandable Lists

Comment: i knoe how to make expandable lists i am tryin to make nested expandable list with the help of multiple listviews..i m so frustrated now

Comment: i have tried clipping the drawable but unfortunately even thats getting force closed. The developers link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip is given but i cant find out where i am going wrong please tell me how to clip it

Comment: I have never used expandable list ; I only know that code samples exist in the SDK. However, what is the force clause message? Do you have any stacktrace? Any log in the logcat console?

Comment: ok thanks i got it... i made nested expandable list view using inflaters and all i was not clear about d concept of inflaters but neways thanks for ur help